Custom font size in TabbedPage .net Maui 8 (iOS)
i'm trying to change the font size for the TabbedPage(not the shell one) in the iOS side, for the moment, i have these changes:
The custom TabbedPage
public partial class CustomTabbedPage : TabbedPage
{
...
}

The renderer
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomTabbedPage), typeof(CustomTabbedPageRenderer))]
namespace MyApp.Platforms.iOS.Renderers
{
    public class CustomTabbedPageRenderer : TabbedRenderer
    {
        public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
        {
            base.ViewWillAppear(animated);
            UpdateAllTabBarItems();
        }

        private void UpdateAllTabBarItems()
        {
            foreach (var controller in ViewControllers)
            {
                UIFont arial = UIFont.FromName("Arial", 50.0f);
                controller?.TabBarItem?.SetTitleTextAttributes(new UIStringAttributes() { Font = arial }, UIControlState.Normal);
            }
        }
    }
}

Added in MauiProgram.cs
ConfigureMauiHandlers((handlers) =>{
     handlers.AddHandler(typeof(CustomTabbedPage), typeof(CustomTabbedPageRenderer));
})

And in the ContentPage:
<renders:CustomTabbedPage>
    <renders:CustomTabbedPage.Children>
        <MyNewPage/> 
    </renders:CustomTabbedPage.Children>
</renders:CustomTabbedPage>

But nothing changes. What i'm doing wrong? i checked the font and it's being created, the ttf is imported well and the config is done. I can change the size of the frame, but not the Font size in iOS.

There is no direct api to change Font size of the Tabbar item. You may raise a feature request on GitHub. But if you would like to use a Shell, here is a thread which configures the font size, How to Increase Font Size for TabBar Menu Items in .NET MAUI on iOS?

You have a renderer but you are adding a handler to your MAUI app, they are two different things.  To add a renderer use AddCompatibilityRenderer
ConfigureMauiHandlers((handlers) =>{
     handlers.AddCompatibilityRenderer(typeof(CustomTabbedPage), typeof(CustomTabbedPageRenderer));
})

